# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' when trying to input CSV data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data into my database but when I try to run it it gives me an error. The data comes from a ASC file and I extract the data, but when I execute the code it gives me an error. This is the code and the error:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function importdb()
{

    $producten= [];
    $File2      = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];
    $handle2    = fopen($File2, "r");
    include('db_config.php');
    while(($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        if  (isset($data2[1]) && mb_strlen($data2[1]) > 0)
        {
            $type             = $data2[0];
            $artikel          = $data2[1];
            $prijs1           = $data2[6];
            $prijs2           = $data2[7];
            $prijs3           = $data2[8];
            $prijs4           = $data2[9];
            $prijs5           = $data2[10];
            if (isset($producten[$artikel]))
            {
                $product_id = $producten[$artikel];
                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `prijzen`(`artikelnr`, `prijs_soort`, `prijs1`, `prijs2`, `prijs3`, `prijs4`, `prijs5`) VALUES (:nmr, :soort, :prijs1, :prijs2, :prijs3, :prijs4, :prijs5)");
                $stmt2->bindParam(":nmr", $artikel);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":soort", $type);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs1", $prijs1);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":product_id", $product_id);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs2", $prijs2);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs3", $prijs3);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs4", $prijs4);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs5", $prijs5);

                $stmt2->execute();

                print_r($data2);

            }else{
                $product_id = $producten[$artikel];
                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `prijzen`(`artikelnr`, `prijs_soort`, `prijs1`, `prijs2`, `prijs3`, `prijs4`, `prijs5`, `product_id`) VALUES (:nmr, :soort, :prijs1, :prijs2, :prijs3, :prijs4, :prijs5, :product_id)");
                $stmt2->bindParam(":nmr", $artikel);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":soort", $type);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs1", $prijs1);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":product_id", $product_id);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs2", $prijs2);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs3", $prijs3);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs4", $prijs4);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs5", $prijs5);

                $stmt2->execute();

                print_r($data2);
            }


        }else{
        }
    }



}
importdb();
```

And this is the error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: 790148 in C:\wamp64\www\jodeco\import.php on line 40
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  379360  {main}( )   ...\import.php:0
2   0.0008  379808  importdb( ) ...\import.php:64



( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '790148' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\wamp64\www\jodeco\import.php on line 51
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '790148' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\wamp64\www\jodeco\import.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  379360  {main}( )   ...\import.php:0
2   0.0008  379808  importdb( ) ...\import.php:64
3   0.0047  409056  execute ( ) ...\import.php:51
```

does this have something to do with the array that I'm creating called $producten? I'm pretty new to using array's.

Does someone know why this happens? It is really bugging me.

Comment: There is a sidebar at the right side, *surprisingly* full with questions on the *exactly* the same problem.

Comment: If the schema is right then the data is wrong. If the data is right then the schema is wrong **neither of which we can see**

Answer (score -1):

This is a case where contemplating the error message can help. Look at the error message. Look for its inner heart, or fu, or gestalt, or whatever you want to call its deep meaning.

To heck with all that. Just **read the message.**  Always read the message. Always read the **end** of the message as well as the beginning.

Looks to me like your CSV file contains more than one line containing the value `790148`. How  to tell this? The error message says

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '790148' for key 'PRIMARY'

It's also possible your table already contains a row with that value, and the CVS file is trying to add the duplicate value.

You may want to read up on `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but certainly not before you review how you want to handle duplicates.